# hook into third party API after checkout

Tags: 6, ubercart

I wondering where to get started on this, I have ubercart core 6.x-2.10 installed and configured with authorize.net.  after a user purchases a "product" I want them to be registered on a third party webinar site. Where in the code would I start are there any extra modules I should use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably be looking to use the [`hook_uc_checkout_complete()`](http://api.ubercart.me/api/drupal/ubercart!docs!hooks.php/function/hook_uc_checkout_complete/6) hook.

From the docs, it takes two parameters, `$order` and `$account` - I'm guessing `$account` will be the one you'll need to create the account on the third party web service as it's the object that contains the customer/user information.

The registration part of your question depends completely on *which* third-party web service you are talking about, and will *probably* fall outside the scope of Drupal Answers unless there is either an existing integration module, or you are looking to write one and need help on the Drupal side of things (i.e. this is not the place for general API usage questions).